# Fan blowing very fast even under no load

Tags: asus, .desktop, lts, fan, 22.04

I am running the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop stable build on my Asus K55VJ-120XD laptop.Even if the the cpu usage is under 5 % the fans are running up at high speed.Average Ram usage is around 2.2 GB/8GB... i already installed the TLP program via command terminal but it didn't worked for me...anything else i can do to solve the problem ???

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. TLP is expected not to have any effect on that.

Comment: how to do that ???

Comment: UEFI is the motherboard's firmware that we used to call BIOS but BIOS isn't actually used since more than a decade ago. So, check the downloads page of the manufacturer for UEFI "BIOS" updates and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try asus-fan control.

https://github.com/dominiksalvet/asus-fan-control

also, you did mention that cpu usage is low, but what are the temperatures. for that you can use Psensor

sudo apt-get -y install psensor

before that you might want need to install sensors and/or lm-sensors.
Maybe the thermal paste/dirt is the issue.

few more recommendations in the direction of cpu power performance:
intel-undervolt,
slimbook-intel,
Cpu Power Manager (gnome extension)

and my most recent discovery
auto-cpufreq - works great

good luck!